# ASP.NET MVC Razor DateTime Validation Error Message

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

So adjournHearingInfo's newHearingDate when I do not fill it in as the error message of

> The value '' is invalid." with a value of "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"

I cannot figure out how to access this check its doing to change this error message. Or if that is not possible remove this check so I can validate the date myself and then generate the error message I want. Is this possible?

Currently I am able to add another error message to it, but I cannot remove that one.

DTO:

```
public class AdjournHearingDTO
{
    public int HearingID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter a Date")]
    [Display(Name ="Additional Hearing Date")]
    [Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/1900","1/1/2060", ErrorMessage =("Please enter a valid date."))]
    public DateTime newHearingDate { get; set; }
}
```

Cshtml:

```
    public AdjournHearingDTO adjournHearingInfo { get; set; } 

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            if (adjournHearingInfo.newHearingDate.Date.ToString() == "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM")
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("adjournHearingInfo.newHearingDate", "Invalid Date");
            };
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form asp-page="AdjournHearing" method="post" name="AdjournHearingScreen" id="AdjournHearingForm">
    @if (!Model.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <h3 class="text-danger">Validation Errors</h3>
                @*@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})*@

                <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="mt-4 mb-3">
            <button asp-page-handler="Back" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</button>
        </h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <h4>Case: @Model.HearingDetail.CaseName</h4>
                <h5>
                    Hearing: @Model.HearingDetail.Name
                </h5>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="card RoundedCorners">
                        <h6>Hearing Date: @Model.NewestHearingDate.ToString("g")</h6>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="adjournHearingInfo.newHearingDate" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="adjournHearingInfo.newHearingDate" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="adjournHearingInfo.newHearingDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="" style="padding:1em 0 0 0;">
                            <button id="SubmitButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Submit </button>
                            <button id="SubmitButtonDisabled" disabled style="display:none" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Submit </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input asp-for="HearingDetail.HearingID" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to wwwroot\lib\jquery-validation\dist\additional-methods.js and find

```
$.validator.messages.date );
```

Try to delete either just the message or the whole line and see if it works.